# How do i find this invisible Load() method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a **winform** with 30 input controls. once i have done all the **save()** started coding the `load()` but the load() does not get called at form load event. When i double clicked on the form for the first time to create Load() it created its Load() event. After coding it, i have accidentally double clicked the form then surprisingly it created another Load() event called "this.FrmNewStudent_Load_1()".

Then i deleted this, but still run-time executes this deleted `load()` event, worst when i double click again it still created the deleted `FrmNewStudent_Load_1()`.

How do i fix this?

PS- i do not want to loose my form!
thank

Comment: Just put your load() event code into load_1() event. Why are you changing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi select the form then go to its properties there in the top there tabs go to event tab and look there for the Load event and there you can see what function is subscribed to the event look for Load Event and changed it to the one you need

Comment: finally the selection of events from the designer drop down worked : )